# How do I make this nested iterator check be much more DRY and efficient?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a `@commit` that `has_many :diffs`, so I have a `@diffs = @commit.diffs`.

Each `diff` has a `.body` which contains a string.

The issue I am running into is that I need to be able to quickly check the `body` of every `diff` that belongs to that `commit` to see if it satisfies some condition (i.e. namely `body.include? (line_count - 3).to_s`). If it does, I want to save/use that `diff`.

The way I have implemented it is by doing this:

```
<% @diffs.each do |diff| %>
    <% if diff.body.include? (line_count - 3).to_s %>
      <% diff.body.lines.each do |dl| %>

      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Which seems inelegant. How can I make this more DRY, efficient and cleaner?

I also would like to take this out of my view, and move into a helper/decorator or something.

Comment: Calling `to_s` on something pretty much guarantees you get a String back, and any string is always logically true. That condition will never not fire.

Answer (score 0):

In general it's correct to say that that sort of logic shouldn't be in the views. I'd recommend using a decorator for this. Take a look at the [Draper](https://github.com/drapergem/draper) gem for helping with this. The below is an example of how you might do this with Draper.

```
# In you controller
class YourController < ApplicationController
  # ...
  @diffs = @commit.diffs.decorate # after adding draper, add `.decorate` to this line in the controller
  # ...
end

# In a Draper decorator
class DiffDecorator < Draper::CollectionDecorator
  def get_some_subset_of_the_diffs
    decorated_collection.select { |diff| diff.body.include? (line_count - 3).to_s }
  end
end

# Your view
<% @diffs.get_some_subset_of_the_diffs.each do |diff| %>
  <% diff.body.lines.each do |dl| %>

  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Also, what are you trying to accomplish with `diff.body.include? (line_count - 3).to_s`? There are cases where this might run, but this probably doesn't perform the logic you want. Is it supposed to detect diffs with less than 3 lines changed?

Comment: Re: your question, no....that logic is checking the string value of the `diff.body` to see if it includes the value of `line_count - 3`, which returns an integer then I need to convert it to a string -- which is what `.to_s` does.

Comment: In that case, you could achieve this with `select`. Updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Why not move the majority of this logic into your models? Assuming you have `Commit` and `Diff` models, you could have:

```
# NOTE: you'll want to change the name "affected" to something that is more meaningful. I don't quite understand what matching on the line count is meant to do here.

class Commit
  def affected_diffs(line_count)
    # the `@diffs ||=` part is optional memoization (read more here: http://gavinmiller.io/2013/basics-of-ruby-memoization/)
    # it can be helpful for performance if you call this method multiple times in your view
    @diffs ||= diffs.select { |diff| diff.affected?(line_count) }
  end
end

class Diff
  # no need to rewrite this logic if you also choose to use it elsewhere
  def affected?(line_count)
    body.include? (line_count - 3).to_s
  end
end

# then in your view
<% @commit.affected_diffs(line_count).each do |diff| %>
  <%# work with each diff %>
<% end %>
```